# Tumbling window with dynamic duration

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

While passing reference data field as a duration in TumblingWindow I am getting compile time error related to Window duration require positive float constant.

Can anyone please guide?

```
group by TumblingWindow(minute, referencetable.EntryTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment we don't support variable time windows, so you need to set the time explicitly and not load it from the reference data. Sorry for the inconvenience.

A workaround, in the case you have only few different time durations, would be to have different steps/subqueries for the different times and use a where clause to create or not an output for that step.

Let me know if you have further question.

JS (from the Azure Stream Analytics team)